# Ambiguous reference when using sbt-native-packager

Tags: sbt, sbt-native-packager

I am trying to use the sbt-native-packager to create a deb file. When I run sbt it complains about ambiguous references as it loads build.sbt:

```
mydir/build.sbt:21: error: reference to maintainer is ambiguous;
it is imported twice in the same scope by
import NativePackagerKeys._
and import _root_.com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager.autoImport._
maintainer in Debian := "Your Name <your@email.com>"

[error] Type error in expression
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore?
```

My build.sbt is:

```
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._
import NativePackagerKeys._

organization := "org.bodhi"

name := "HelloRemote"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.4"

resolvers += "Typesafe Repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.3.4",
  "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-remote" % "2.3.4"
)

packageArchetype.java_application

maintainer in Debian := "Your Name <your@email.com>"
```

I am using sbt 0.13.7; My packager.sbt file contains:
    addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-native-packager" % "1.0.0-M3")

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Just remove import NativePackagerKeys._

Comment: Thank you, this works, but contradicts the plugin's documentation: http://www.scala-sbt.org/sbt-native-packager/DetailedTopics/debian.html Additionally if I use 'maintainer in Debian := Joe" I still get the error. Is this a case where the documentation is not current, and not all bugs are ironed oout?

Comment: I use sbt-native-packager-1.0.0-M3 and use following imports:   import com.typesafe.sbt.packager.Keys._
import com.typesafe.sbt.SbtNativePackager._